# Syntax error: Encountered "BEGIN"

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

This is my first time to create a stored procedure in derby query. I'm trying to create a Procedure. When I try to run my query it gives me a error Encountered "BEGIN"

**CODE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show_name(IN USERNAME VARCHAR(50), IN PASSWORD VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM LISTNAME
END
```

**ERROR**

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "BEGIN" at line 3, column 1.
```

How can I get rid of this error? I'm a little bit confused creating procedure in derby.

Comment: AFAIK, Derby [stored procedures](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefcreateprocedurestatement.html) need to be written in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how can I create EXTERNAL NAME? Thanks. I'm still confused creating this store procedure

Comment: By writing a Java `static` method in a `class`.

Comment: Can you please show some examples where can I have a good start writing a stored procedure. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments on the question, the implementation of Apache Derby stored procedures are Java (`public static`) methods. See the Apache Derby Wiki article [DerbySQLRoutines](https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines), specifically the section *Creating Procedures*, that contains a simple example of how to create a stored procedure.

The following are extracts are taken from the linked Wiki article.

The SQL create procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DRS2(DP1 INTEGER, DP2 INTEGER)
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
LANGUAGE JAVA
READS SQL DATA
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2
EXTERNAL NAME 'org.apache.derbyTesting.functionTests.util.ProcedureTest.selectRows'
```

The static Java method that is the procedure implementation:

```
public static void selectRows(int         p1,
                              int         p2,
                              ResultSet[] data1,
                              ResultSet[] data2)
    throws SQLException
{
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
  PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from t1 where i = ?");
  ps1.setInt(1, p1);
  data1[0] = ps1.executeQuery();

  PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from t1 where i >= ?");
  ps2.setInt(1, p2);
  data2[0] = ps2.executeQuery();

  conn.close();
}
```

Note a try-with-resources clause would preferable to the explicit `conn.close()` shown.

---

In the event the link breaks I searched for "*Apache Derby Stored Procedures*".